# Synapse linked service "Azure Synapse Analytics" has wrong authentication type after deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I want to deploy a linked service of type "Azure Synapse Analytics" using authentication type "System Assigned Managed Identity" via Azure DevOps release pipeline using task "Synapse workspace deployment". The deployment itself works and the linked service is created. However, the authentication method in the target Synapse Workspace is set to "SQL authentication" rather than "System Assigned Managed Identity".

[image]

When I compare the linked service json in the source and target environment, the target always has the connection string of type "SecureString" which seems to mess up the authentication type.

**Source**

```
"type": "AzureSqlDW",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=@{linkedService().Server};Initial Catalog=@{linkedService().DB}"
    }
```

**Target**

```
"type": "AzureSqlDW",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": {
            "type": "SecureString",
            "value": "**********"
        }
    }
```

I tried following which did not solve the issue and still creates the linked service with type "SQL authentication".

- setting the connection string parameter in the DevOps task to ""
- setting the connection string parameter in the DevOps task to "Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=@{linkedService().Server};Initial Catalog=@{linkedService().DB}"

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

**EDIT**
In the meantime I setup a completely new Synapse Workspace and there it works. The only difference I can spot is that in the generated TemplateForWorkspace.json the connection string for the linked service is NOT of type "SecureString" even though the parameter definition is of type "SecureString".

**parameters**

```
        "AzureSynapseAnalytics1_connectionString": {
        "type": "secureString",
        "metadata": "Secure string for 'connectionString' of 'AzureSynapseAnalytics1'",
        "defaultValue": "Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=xxxx.sql.azuresynapse.net;Initial Catalog=test"
    }
```

**resources**

```
            "name": "[concat(parameters('workspaceName'), '/AzureSynapseAnalytics1')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/linkedServices",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
        "properties": {
            "annotations": [],
            "type": "AzureSqlDW",
            "typeProperties": {
                "connectionString": "[parameters('AzureSynapseAnalytics1_connectionString')]"
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": []
```

Comment: @ Raffael Can you check this if it helps to resolve your issue with Authenication type
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1100079/connection-string-for-parameterized-linked-service

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Unfortunately not. This is one of the approaches I tried but it still sets the authentication type to "SQL Authentication".